# Delete from Bootstrap Date filled with data from mysql converted to json array

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, twitter-bootstrap

Not sure if i am making life complicated for my self but here is the following code. What i want to achieve is when a user clicks the checkbox and the delete button is clicked the record is delete. The record is held in a mysql database. I have retrieved the data using php and converting to a json array.

The Bootstrap Table

```
<div class="col col-xs-6 text-right">
                <?php include 'modals/adduser.php';
                ?>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-create" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">New User</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-delete">Delete User</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <table id="userstable" data-toggle="table" data-url="tables/userstable.php"   data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true">checkbox</th>
                            <th data-field="uname"  data-sortable="true">Username</th>                
                            <th data-field="userName" data-sortable="true">Full Name</th>
                            <th data-field="userEmail"  data-sortable="true">Email Address</th>
                            <th data-field="userRole" data-sortable="true">User Level</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                    </table>
```

The file that retrieves the data for the table.

```
  <?php 
    include'../connect.php';

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT uname, userName, userEmail, userRole FROM users");

    $json_array = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
            $json_array[] = $row;
    }

echo json_encode($json_array);

?>
```

When the user clicks a checkbox it gives it a class of selected. I know I need a script to get the row with that selected class and pass the information back to a delete php file but I can't seem to work it out. Have been trying to work it out myself reading online the last couple of days but cant seem to crack it so any help is really appreciated. Hopefully one day I wont be asking the questions but answering them.

Comment: If you want to pass the response `echo json_encode()` you need to use an ajax call in order to fetch data from your database. Additionally I don't see the `<body></body>` in your table.

Comment: Is this PHP and HTML code in different files?

Comment: Are you populating the table with some ajax / javascript function ? Cause I can't see any data into the table, only headers. If yes, you just need to get the value of the checkbox (an ID to refer to the user) and pass it the same way you do while retrieving the data(json) but instead of a SELECT statement a "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = $id".

Also I hardly recommend you to use PDO instead, to prevent SQL injection

Comment: @Franco I havent copied my entire page over to here as it would take up alot of room. I have show how my bootstrap table is built in one file then below is a seperate file that gets the data to display in the table. This is set by data-url on the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the following assumptions:

- Your HTML and PHP code are in the same page.
- `uname` column is unique for `users` table i.e. this column doesn't contain any duplicate values.

Instead of `json_encode`ing the array, simply loop through the result set and display each row in it's own table row, plus one last table row as a placeholder for the *delete* input button. Also, wrap the entire `<tbody>` with a `form` and make the `checkbox` input element like this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row['uname']; ?>" /></td>
```

So after form submission, `$_POST['users']` will contain an array of `uname`s you want to delete. Overall, your code should be like this:

```
// your code

<table id="userstable" data-toggle="table" data-url="tables/userstable.php" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true">checkbox</th>
        <th data-field="uname"  data-sortable="true">Username</th>                
        <th data-field="userName" data-sortable="true">Full Name</th>
        <th data-field="userEmail"  data-sortable="true">Email Address</th>
        <th data-field="userRole" data-sortable="true">User Level</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <form action="yourPage.php" method="post">
        <?php
            include'../connect.php';
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT uname, userName, userEmail, userRole FROM users");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row['uname']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['uname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['userName']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['userEmail']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['userRole']; ?></td>
                </tr>
               <?php
            }
        ?>
        <tr colspan="5"><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="delete" /></td></tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
</table>

// your code
```

**Note:** Don't forget to change `action="yourPage.php"` with your page.

And after form submission, process/delete them like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST['users'] as $uname){

        // perform delete operation based on the $uname

    }
}
```

---

If you want to see the complete array structure, do `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Thanks for your response @Rajdeep Paul. The table and the database data retriveal are in seperate files. Could I like you say simple contain the table in a form and then have a delete button in the top of the table. Your example above i presume has a delete button on every row of the table?

Comment: @MartinToye No, there's only one delete button for the entire table. What you'll do here is, you checked the row(s) you want to delete and hit the delete button. After the form submission, you can delete each of the checked rows using `foreach` loop. Test your application with the given code snippets, hope this will resolve your issue. By the way, is there's any specific reason why you've separated HTML and PHP code in different files?

Comment: Sorry one more question before trying it out. Will this work with pagination.

Comment: @MartinToye Yes, this will also work with pagination.

Comment: have updated the code and button doesn't show. Last row is just a checkbox.

Comment: When you refresh the page you see a quick flash of the button but then disappears when loaded.

Comment: @MartinToye Paste your code on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/index.php) and give me it's link here.

Comment: @MartinToye I *partially* recreated the issue(removed all `include` and `$_SESSION` statements and retained the necessary HTML and PHP code), and it's working fine for me. What issue you're facing now?

Comment: If I don't keep the include statements and $_session statements the header and footer won't work and I won't be able to clarify is a user is logged in.

Comment: @MartinToye No, I didn't mean you need to remove those things from your code, I removed those `include`, `$_SESSION` things just to recreate the issue. Can you provide a screenshot where it's causing the problem, I mean what happens when the user logs in, what does the user see etc.? Are the table, rows, checkboxes, delete button rendered properly?

Comment: Apologies i misunderstood. The delete button is not rendered properly. All that appears on the row with the delete button is additional checkbox and thing else. I'll will grad a screen shot a put it up

Comment: I have also tried putting the delete button in the panel heading next two the new user button and it appears there ok but doesn't function properly. I.e doesn't delete the user.

Comment: @MartinToye The *delete* input element should be part of the `<form>`, which means you have to place the *delete* button somewhere between opening `<form action="..." ...>` and  closing `</form>`. I'm sure you've placed the *delete* button outside of your form, that's why it's not working.

Comment: Sorry apologies i moved the form opening tag as well above the delete button so it was included in the form.

Comment: @MartinToye Share your code using pastebin. Also, provide a screenshot of your page, where it is rendered incorrectly. And just for the debugging purpose, remove all JavaScript code from your page.

Comment: see links for screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxPqf5kJ5hdGMWd2WW1hMnFQZFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If I remove the delete button where you put in in your code snippet that row with just the checkbox goes. You should see in the screenshot as well where i have placed the button in my code on the top right. And the paste bin shows the code.

Comment: @MartinToye [1/2] Too many unknowns here. 1) The last row has nothing to do with *delete* button, plus are you sure you deleted the entire row `<tr colspan="5"><td>{delete button}</td></tr>`? 2) *Showing 1 to 4 of 4 rows* clearly shows that you're doing something wrong with the **pagination**, or may be last(4th) row is blank. 3) You didn't even change the `action="yourPage.php"` from your form. 4) Is there any JavaScript in your code which is manipulating the table rows?

Comment: @MartinToye [2/2] 5) The *New User* button won't do anything because it's of `button` type, make it as `submit`. 6) Make use of `var_dump($_POST);` to check what you're getting after submitting the form. 7) Everything is working on my end, I'm not sure why it's not working for you, debug it further using the above mentioned points.